# Can I make auto login on my website using local facebook android app login info?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, authentication

I would like to make auto login on my web site tto as I login in my android app. Mostly, this web will be shown on android. So I want to make my user easy to login when they use my web site.

Right now, I can see only login with javascript on facebook developer page. For it, we need to type user's id and password.

I wonder that is there any way to get login information from their local `facebook` application to auto login on my website using `javascript` if they are not logged in on web.

Thank you to read this.
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this. the SSO (Single Sign On) feature can´t be used for Websites, only for other (native) Apps afaik.